# Redis INCRBY with limits

Tags: lua, redis

I'd like to know if there is a way to perform this in redis with a single roundtrip from my app:

For a given key `K`, its possible value `V` is any of the integers inside the range `[A, B]`. Basically, it has an upper and lower boundary.

When an `INCRBY` or `DECRBY` command is issued (eg. `INCRBY key 10`) it will be executed **only** if the resulting value is not out of bounds.

I need this operation to be atomic, and I wanted to know if there was a way to avoid Lua scripting for this.

Thank you.

Comment: 1. Why do you want to avoid lua scripting? 2. Does `B - A == 2^n - 1`?

Comment: @for_stack I am trying to avoid LUA as I've never used it, and this piece of code need to be crystal clear for me. About the range, it is a normal interval... basically, I want to have a score that goes from 0 to 100, and events increase and decrease points, but never going under 0 or over 100. The problem is that 50 events can happen in the very same second, so atomicity is a **must**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer might not be what you expect. But I have to say that Lua scripting is the crystal clear solution.

```
-- range-incrby.lua key , increment
local key = KEYS[1]
local increment = ARGV[1]
local cnt = redis.call('get', key) or 0
cnt = cnt + increment
if (cnt >= 0 and cnt <= 100) then
    redis.call('set', key, cnt)
    return cnt
end
```

Also, if the range is `[0, 2^N - 1]`, then you can use `BITFIELD` command with overflow control to solve the problem.

```
BITFIELD key OVERFLOW FAIL INCRBY uN 0 increment
```

However, that seems not your case.

Comment: The right answer imo too. Minor comments: Lua, not "lua" and always better to use `ARGS` and externalize the arguments... even in examples ;)

Comment: @ItamarHaber Thanks for the comments! B.T.W you CANNOT replace `ARGV` with `ARGS`. Or do I misunderstand anything?

Comment: Meant `ARGV` of course (damn auto correct). I'd like to reciprocate and thank you for becoming more active in SO/Redis questions - I've been watchin you you know ;)

Comment: @ItamarHaber I'm glad to hear that :)

Comment: Thank you, I'll give a try to it. I didn't want to mess with another more language, but it is pretty clear, and at the end, the purpose is more important that personal preference ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree that the Lua script solution is clear and efficient. In that case, another variation taking the limit and decrement as a argument can be implemented as.

```lua
local value=redis.call("get", KEYS[1]) or 0
local decrement=tonumber(ARGV[1])
local limit=tonumber(ARGV[2])

if (value - decrement) < limit then value = redis.call("decrby", KEYS[1], value - limit)
else value = redis.call("decrby", KEYS[1], decrement) end
return value
```