# Set redis value only if the stored value is smaller/bigger

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

Is there a built-in command which sets a value of a stored key, only if that value is smaller/bigger then some parameter?

Or my only solution here is to make two calls to the cache - one for checking the value, the other one (possible one) for storing a new value?

Thanks

Comment: build in commands https://redis.io/commands

Comment: No built in command for that. But you can use Lua script to do the work. Check [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43632880/redis-incrby-with-limits/43639921) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a simple command for this, but you could try using a Lua script that wouldn't require multiple client commands, something like:

```
local currentValue = tonumber(redis.call('GET', KEYS[1]))

if not currentValue or (ARGV[1] == 'smaller' and tonumber(ARGV[2]) < currentValue) or (ARGV[1] == 'larger' and tonumber(ARGV[2]) > currentValue) then
    redis.call('SET', KEYS[1], ARGV[2])
    return true
else
    return false
end
```